# How do I create a mapping from param (char* in_buffer, int len) in C++ to C# in Swig?

Tags: c#, swig

I'm trying to use SWIG 2.0.11 to wrap a C++ function in C#.  I want to pass a C++ buffer in as a parameter and have this appear as an array in C#.

In C++ I have

```
void process_buffer(unsigned char* in_buffer, int len);
```

In C# I would like this to appear as

```
void process_buffer(byte[] in_buffer);
```

These are the key requirements:

- I don't care if the array is pinned or not.
- I don't want the len param to appear in C#.
- The buffer is IN only.

Right now, I can only make this work by having the len param also appear in C#, which I don't want.

Is there are a built-in way to do this in SWIG?  If there's not, I'm surprised!  What is the overview on how to go about it if I have to do it "manually"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SWIG typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps_nn2) but this is quite complicated for average SWIG user; or you can create a C# function that converts the one arg (a byte array) to the one that takes two parameters:

```
// yourUtils.cs
using YourCppUtils; // module generated by SWIG, containing process_buffer(char[], int)
void process_buffer(byte[] in_buffer) 
{
    char[] chars = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).ToCharArray();
    process_buffer(chars, chars.Length); // calls the sWIG-wrapped version
}
```